# How do I redirect with dev_appserver?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, redirect

I have a simple login script that checks mysql for authentication of the user and then redirects to the start page of the application using the php 'header' function.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($dbq)==1) {
header("Location: header.html");
}
```

where header.html is in the same directory as index.php, but it seems to ignore this completely. The log simply says;

```
INFO     2016-03-22 13:36:48,421 module.py:787] default: "POST /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 301
INFO     2016-03-22 13:36:48,517 module.py:787] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 301
```

Here is some more info - if I put

```
- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

I get the http status of 301, but if I remove this handler the redirection works.

Here is current app.yaml file;

```
application: crm
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
# Serve php scripts.
#- url: /.*
# script: index.php
#- url: /.*
# script: header.html
- url: /(.+\.php)$
script: \1
- url: /(.+\.html)$
script: \1

# Serve images as static resources.
- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg))$
static_files: \1
upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg)$
application_readable: true
```

Comment: Could it be that `mysqli_num_rows($dbq) != 1`? If not - did you try to `exit()` after `header()` in case something overwrites it later on?

Comment: Yes I have added the exit() after the header() with no luck. I have added some info to the OP though.

Comment: You should provide your entire `app.yaml` file. The issue is probably in not properly handling static html files. Also, [configuring with app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#PHP_app_yaml_About_app_yaml) article might be helpful for a proper PHP `app.yaml` set up.

Comment: Ok, I have added full contents of file, much of which I got from the link you prvided. :)

Comment: OK, I gave up and used javascript to do the redirection. I'm new to appengine and I must say it is extremely frustrating.